# Cordova plugin to connect to a extern Database? (not microsoft)

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, cordova, plugins

I need a plugin for a Cordova project which allows me to connect to a database. (in my case it's an RDS Amazon Web Server database with Mysql community as engine). I already tried the Cordova-plugin-SQLServer, but it doesn't seem to work.

**I tried:**

```
SqlServer.init("myAmazonWebserverEndpoint", "SQLEXPRESS", "player", "mypassword", "BuchungsDatenbank", function(event) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(event));
}, function(error) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(error));
});


SqlServer.testConnection(function(event) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(event));
}, function(error) {
        alert("Error : " + JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

Even though the init worked, the test connection didn't. I think this plugin only works on Microsoft SQLServer databases.

The plugin is on this page: [cordova-plugin-SQLServer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-sqlserver) Does someone know a plugin which works also with other databases?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Check the link as that link is a 404 page..

Comment: *"I already tried the Cordova-plugin-SQLServer, but it doesn't seem to work. "* SQL Server (Microsoft SQL) is not the same as MySQL, they use a totally different server/client protocol so it's niet wierd you can't connect..

Comment: Also for which platform do you need it?  Can't you check the source code behide [cordova-mysql-android](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-mysql-android) and reverse engineer it into the platform you need? -> [Plugin Development Guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html)